# How to use "remark" to process Markdown files containing some URLs without markdown formatting? Any extra plugins?

Tags: javascript, next.js, markdown, remarkjs

I have following markdown file with frontmatter. The markdown content sometimes contains inline URLs which are not formatted with markdown's URL syntax. Is there any way to deal with those non-markdown URLs inside the markdown file, and somehow parse them into HTML urls with some regex plugin, etc? Need little tip here from experienced front end guys

```
Example .md file:
---
category: "general"
medium: "forum"
date: "July 25, 2010"
---

For future reference, here's my public key. **http://www.iamyourfather.org/papa.asc**
```

I then as usual process with with remark using the HTML plugin like this:

```
// Use gray-matter to parse the quote metadata section
const matterResult = matter(fileContents)

// Use remark to convert markdown into HTML string
const processedContent = await remark()
    .use(html)
    .process(matterResult.content)

const contentHtml = processedContent.toString()
```

I would like this "contentHtml" string to contain proper clickable HTML link in case the content of the markdown contains such plaintext http/www urls.

Is there a way to combine remark, remark-html, and ANOTHER plugin to parse this in single shot?
Do i need multiple steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching, is the GFM auto-link functionality.

With [remark](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-gfm#api), you use it like this:

```js
const file = await remark()
  .use(remarkGfm)
  .process(input)
```

`Remark-gfm` is a package that contains the two needed pieces:

- the parsing with [gfm-autolink-literal](https://github.com/micromark/micromark-extension-gfm-autolink-literal).
- and the tree creation [mdast-util-gfm-autolink-literal](https://github.com/syntax-tree/mdast-util-gfm-autolink-literal)